# Parse Query "cannot resolve symbol"

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform

I'm working on `Parse` with android and I need to query some data stored. But I am unable to use any query command except for `query.CachePolicy`. All the other methods like `query.getFirstinBackground` are turned red and studio says "cannot resolve symbol".

I have ensured that I included the necessary imports such as `com.Parse.Query` and `com.Parse.Object`. But I'm unable to use any query operations.

This is the code I'm trying to add

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Posted");
    query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
        if (object == null) {
            Log.d("RBSE", "The getFirst request failed.");
        } else {
            // got the most recently modified object... do something with it here
        }
    }
}
```

Why am I getting this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like, I used the query statements under wrong class in my java file. 
Using them on under onActivityCreated class, solved the problem.